# Cannot query MySQL database via PHP

Tags: php, mysql

In my PHP code, i'm easily writing records to my database but for some reason i can't read anythign out. My PHP code is:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM companies";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
{
    echo "query success";

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "ID: " . $row["ID"]. " - Name: " . $row["name"]. "<br>";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "query failure";
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO companies (name) 
        VALUES ('mycompany')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
{

    echo "insert success";
}
else
{
    echo "insert failure";
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

The output I get from the browser when i run it is:
`query failureError: SELECT * FROM companies
insert success`

I've tried variations of apostrophes, carets, quotes in that $sql string. I've tried running this query in HeidiSQL and it works fine. Any ideas where I'm going wrong? Any suggestions of more basic stuff I can try to narrow down the source of the problem?

thanks!

Comment: You don't actually bind the results from your query, `if ($result = $conn->query($sql))`. But that's not the source of your issue, take a look at [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) and [`error_reporting(-1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

Comment: You should consider using a condition so that either the select is run, or the insert is run, or the insert is run after the select, or the select is run after the insert.  Right now, your code is re-using the same variable without any controls on when that variable is assigned a new value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `mysqli->query()` with a `SELECT` statement returns an instance of `mysqli_result`. It is not identical to true (`=== true`), but nor does it represent an error.

Moreover, `$result` is undefined.

Use this instead:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM companies";

if (($result = $conn->query($sql)) !== FALSE)
{
    echo "query success";

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "ID: " . $row["ID"]. " - Name: " . $row["name"]. "<br>";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "query failure";
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
...
```

This simply changes your `=== TRUE` check to `!== FALSE`. `MySQLi::query()` returns boolean FALSE on failure, boolean TRUE on a successful query without result sets or a `mysqli_result` upon success with a result set.
This also assigns the result of query() into `$result`.

Comment: Looks like the OP took off without saying goodbye and not leaving a nice fat tip ;-)

Comment: Good comments from everyone. I would say that all the information I received helped to solve this. Actually I was thinking perhaps I should be doing this to test the query results `$result = $conn->query($sql); if ($result->num_rows > 0)` Anyone agree with that?

Comment: @mitch Yes, that would make more sense Mitch, however it could fail (at some point) and you would need to use a `WHERE` clause (it could work better) >>> depending on what you're really wanting to achieve here. You could use `mysqli_error($conn)` on query error though, or a mix of.

Comment: @mitch that could result in a `Trying to get property of non-object`, since `$result === false` if query failed.

Comment: Thanks. I'm now checking `if($result !== FALSE)` followed by my check on `$result->num_rows`. Does that seem good?

Comment: Yes. But it depends on what kind of result you expected from database - one row? multiple rows? or what? I am asking this because you don't have a WHERE clause in your query and it appears that you expect an arbitrary amount of columns? Because fetch_assoc() will simply return null if it is an empty result set, but it will ultimately return null when all rows have been read, so usually you don't need to explicitly check if it is an empty result set or not, unless you only expect one column and there has to be one column.

Answer (score 1):

You have not assign the query result to `$result` variable.

```
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM companies";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result === TRUE)
    {
        echo "query success";

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            echo "ID: " . $row["ID"]. " - Name: " . $row["name"]. "<br>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "query failure";
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }


    $sql = "INSERT INTO companies (name) 
            VALUES ('mycompany')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
    {

        echo "insert success";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "insert failure";
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a **SELECT** query will return a **mysqli_result** object on SUCCESS not a boolean TRUE. Only if the query fails, will it return a boolean FALSE;

Therefore you should use it like this :

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result !== FALSE){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "ID: " . $row["ID"]. " - Name: " . $row["name"]. "<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just change your if condition :-

```
if ($result = $conn->query($sql))
{
    echo "query success";

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "ID: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["name"]. "<br>";
    }
}
```