# PHP POST not saving my data in mysql , checking my api using postman

Tags: php, mysql, json, rest

I am playing around with php, i wish to make a simple api to save my `name` field in database using **chrome postman**

The is my php code:

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,x-prototype-version,x-requested-with');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=900');
header("Content-Type: application/json"); // tell client that we are sending json data


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$dxname  =$_GET['name'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO crudtable(firstname, lastname, email,favjob)
VALUES ('".$dxname."', 'Doe', 'john@example.com','coder')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo json_encode("New record created successfully");
   // echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo json_encode("Some error");
   // echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

When i am using postman , 
1. the name is not getting saved in db **[only hard coded values are being saved]**
2. I am not getting `echo json_encode("New record created successfully");` once data is saved.

Please help, attaching screenshot of my postman result and how i am passing the name variable

[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRr01.png)

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Do try and get out of the habit of cluttering up your code with needless things like `=== TRUE`. Many functions are designed to return values that evaluate as logically true or false so that's redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending data through post method and you are using GET.

Change:

```
$dxname  =$_GET['name'];
```

To

```
$dxname  =$_POST['name'];
```

ALso:

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
```

To

```
if ($result = $conn->query($sql))
{ echo json_encode("New record created successfully");
   // echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo json_encode("Some error");
   // echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

[Cannot query MySQL database via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34228090/cannot-query-mysql-database-via-php)

Comment: data saved but still not getting the success message, i am getting same thing in postman, see above attached image or i am copying message here aswell - `<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home2/saurabh/public_html/edits/pro/users/funiks/adminv8/products-api/crudtable-add.php:2) in
<b>/home2/saurabh/public_html/edits/pro/users/funiks/adminv8/products-api/crudtable-add.php</b> on line
<b>4</b>`

Comment: i think you don't need to add headers

Comment: worked without header, but if i am sending data in json i'll be needing it, right ?

Answer (score 0):

Json should be an array.. try this

```
echo json_encode(array("Success"));
```

where did you get the $_GET method? can you show us the html page? you can try using
 `$_POST['name'];`

Comment: json issue still there